# What would a SPDY "Hello world" look like?

Tags: optimization, spdy

I just finished skimming the [SPDY white paper](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper) and now I'm interested in trying it out. I understand that [Google is serving content over SSL to Chrome using SPDY](http://groups.google.com/group/spdy-dev/browse_thread/thread/4c2396ecbc36b1c4).

What's the easiest way to set up and serve a basic "Hello world" HTML page over SPDY?

Answer (score 3):

Run an existing spdy server such as:

https://github.com/indutny/node-spdy

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that the quickest and easiest way would be to follow the [instructions located here](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/running_flipinmemserver).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [spdylay](http://spdylay.sourceforge.net/) SPDY library in C and recently added Python wrapper [python-spdylay](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spdylay/).
It needs Python 3.3.0 (which is RC1 at the time of this writing),
but you can write simple SPDY server just like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import spdylay

# private key file
KEY_FILE='server.key'
# certificate file
CERT_FILE='server.crt'

class MySPDYRequestHandler(spdylay.BaseSPDYRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('content-type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')

        content = '''\
<html><head><title>SPDY</title></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1>
</body></html>'''.encode('UTF-8')

        self.wfile.write(content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 3000

    server = spdylay.ThreadedSPDYServer((HOST, PORT),
                                        MySPDYRequestHandler,
                                        cert_file=CERT_FILE,
                                        key_file=KEY_FILE)
    server.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The intention of SPDY is that it is entirely transparent to your webapplication.  You don't need to write code to use SPDY, you just need to use a webserver that supports it.

If you have a java web application, then you can SPDY enable it by using Jetty.  3 simple steps: add a jar to the boot path to enable NPN, create an SSL certificate for your server, configure SPDY as the connector type.   See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/SPDY

This will be even easier in Jetty-9